# Dont show me again checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter, configparser

I want a window with "don't show me again" (a toplevel-window). If this box get's checked, I don't want it showing me this window another time.

```
import configparser
from tkinter import *
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()     #my ini file
config.add_section('Section1')
config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'False')
with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
root = Tk()
def var_states():                          #write to ini file
    global mt
    print(config.read('ayrlar.ini'))
    if var1 == True:
        config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'True')
        with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        global window
        window.destroy()
    elif var1 == False:
        config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'False')
        with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
            global window
            window.destroy()
var1 = config.getboolean('Section1', 'a_bool')
def show():                           #if checkbox is true
    global window                     #dont show
    window= Toplevel(root)
    Checkbutton(window, text="Don't show me again", variable=var1).place(x=0, y=0)
    Button(window, text='Okey', command=var_states).place(x=0, y=25)
root.after(10,show)
root.mainloop()
```

When run another time I don't want show this window. How can I do this with `ConfigParser`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: you can see my code i want only whats my code problem why not work

Answer (score 0):

For the variable of a `Checkbutton` to work, it should be an `IntVar` or a `BooleanVar`. So I replaced the `var1` in your code by a `BooleanVar`:

```
def var_states():                          #write to ini file
    global mt
    print(config.read('ayrlar.ini'))
    if  var1.get():
        config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'True')
        with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        global window
        window.destroy()
    else:
        config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'False')
        with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
            global window
            window.destroy()
var1 = BooleanVar(root, value=config.getboolean('Section1', 'a_bool'))
```